# GUI for Ubuntu Server without Internet

Tags: installation, wireless, networking, server

I am first time on this community. So, even I have a problem but I am still excited about it :). I recently installed Ubuntu Server edition 12.04 however I figured out that it did not install any GUI (as expected) as it is a server opposed to desktop. Now, I would like to install some stuff like the Gnome/KDE or alternative desktops. I know I need the internet for that however I do not have ethernet configured. I can only use Wifi-dongle (USB-N10) from Asus which is basic and requires software I believe. In other words, I can't run apt-get to install further stuff into it. Could anybody please help me with

1. How I could install the GUI without internet (of course I have CD)
2. Alternatively, I could install the USB driver which I believe must be trickier than the first choice.

Any help will be highly appreciated :), thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question:

> 1) How I could install the GUI without internet (of course I have CD) ?

You might have been assumed that, you can install GUI softwares from the server CD, which is not the case. You need the packages files (which are basically .deb files) from an Internet enabled PC, and then use those files to install software on your PC.

Look at this question for detail instruction: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline).

For your second question, I suggest you to create another separate question with mentioning your specific USB device. That is the recommended way for un-cluttering the site.

Comment: Thanks Anwar! I found another post which I believe is very enlightening, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=972693, so it means I could use the CD-ROM as one of apt source, also, trying 'ubuntu server how to switch to desktop without internet' on google was very resourceful too, that might help quite much. I appreciate your time regarding my post! :)

Comment: If you think, the answer helped you, you could upvote or possibly accept the answer. But in this case, I see you have found an answer in Ubuntuforum. I suggest you to add your own answer here, so that people can quickly find it. Thanks!